# Custom Adapter Not showing data

Tags: android, xml, fragment, custom-adapter

I have developed an custom adapter which takes data from SQLite. Data is selecting and adapter also gets data. But its not showing in the list view. I don't get any errors. I printed data get in the adapter but only one set of data is shown. Not all data.

I have developed and follow normal custom adapter implementation example.

I have some doubts.

1-In my customAdapter class.  when i am inflating XML for the custom rows in adapter when findviewById() is called only one Text View shows 'it may produce null pointer Exception'.Why ? my xml for list view row.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:paddingBottom="6dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_item_name"
        android:textColor="@color/item_name_color"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_item_price"

        android:textColor="@color/item_price_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_item_contains"

        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_below="@id/row_item_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row_item_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/row_item_quantity"
        android:layout_above="@id/row_item_contains"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/row_item_price" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

1. In my fragment class also above warning shows for inflated list view element.
   my fragments xml is given below.

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tableTextview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="left"
       android:text="@string/table"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/userName"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:textColor="@color/bg" />



   <EditText
       android:paddingTop="6dp"
       android:id="@+id/tableNumber"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:maxWidth="@dimen/tableNoSize"
       android:layout_below="@id/tableTextview"
       android:layout_alignRight="@id/tableTextview"
       android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tableTextview" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tableNumber"
       android:layout_alignStart="@id/tableNumber"
       android:layout_below="@id/tableNumber"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:paddingTop="6dip"
       android:paddingBottom="4dip"
       android:text="@string/Menu" />

   <ListView
       android:layout_below="@id/textView"
       android:id="@+id/bearer_menu_order_list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp">
   </ListView>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/placeButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/textView"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="@color/buttonColor"
       android:text="@string/placeOrder" />
   ```

my Adapter code

```
    public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<MenuData> list;
    private Context context;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, List<MenuData> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        Log.e("Hee",list.size()+"");
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Log.e("list got--",""+list.size());
        Log.e("position ",""+position);

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_create_new,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            try{
                holder.txtName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_name);
                holder.txtContains=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_contains);
                holder.txtPrice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_price);
                holder.txtQuantity=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_quantity);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                Log.e("covertView-","Null");
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else {
            Log.e("covertView-","Not Null");
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MenuData currentRow=list.get(position);
        Log.e("item ",currentRow.getKEY_ITEM_NAME());
        holder.txtName.setText(currentRow.getKEY_ITEM_NAME());
        holder.txtContains.setText(currentRow.getKEY_ITEM_CONTENTS());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(currentRow.getKEY_PRICE());

        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtPrice;
        public TextView txtContains;
        public TextView txtQuantity;

    }

}
```

fragment code is

```
 public class CreateOrderFragment extends Fragment {

    List<MenuData> listMenu;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        listMenu=new ArrayList<MenuData>();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_new_order_list_sections, container, false);
        Context context=getActivity();
        //View view=getView();
        ListView menuList;
        menuList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list);
        menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
        listMenu = helper.getMenuItem();
        Log.e("list menu--",listMenu.size()+"");
        MenuListAdapter adapter=new MenuListAdapter(context,listMenu);
        Log.e("list adapter--",""+adapter.getCount());
        menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
        menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String user;
        TextView tv;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your Adapter code then.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code sa well.

Comment: now post your Fragment code

Comment: Where is code of binding adapter into your ListView ?

Comment: menuList.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Where you have added the data into your ArrayList ? What does your `helper.getMenuItem();` contains ?

Comment: listMenu = helper.getMenuItem(); // function to get data from database  which returns list<Menudata> menudata is a bean class to hold data

Comment: I suggest you to keep the code which you have written in your `onActivityCreated` into the `onCreateView` method. As the `onActivityCreated` always gets called before `onCreateView`.

Comment: and also if you are working with the same code then you need to `Extends` your `Fragment` to `ListFragment`

Comment: @GrIsHu ur comment is right.

Comment: @GrIsHu is fragment class have onCreateView method??

Comment: @Rashid yes it has....

Comment: @Rashid The `Fragments` `onCreateView` method is similar to the method of `onCreate` method of `Activity`. Which is used to inflate the layout. So the thing is happening is like as you have written all the code in `onActivityCreate`method and then its inflating your layout. So you must have kept `ListView` default invisible in your layout file. That is why its not showing you listview.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one set of data is shown"? Are you _certain_ that all of the expected data is being retrieved from the db, and that the Adapter is getting it?

Comment: its showing error for me. thats why i ask so.

Comment: @Rashid You just write all your code of `onActivityCreate` method and `onCreate` method into the `onCreateView` method. And then check

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @MikeM. listMenu = helper.getMenuItem(); gets the all values. also adapter is getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple implement onCreateView() for Fragment.

```
 ListView menuList;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_new_order_list_sections, container, false); 
    menuList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list);
    DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    listMenu = helper.getMenuItem();
    Log.e("list menu--",listMenu.size()+"");
    MenuListAdapter adapter=new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(),listMenu);
    Log.e("list adapter--",""+adapter.getCount());
    menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
    menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   return rootView;
 }
```

And in your Adapter class change here also

```
 public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private List<MenuData> list;
 private Context context;

 public MenuListAdapter(Context context, List<MenuData> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    Log.e("Hee",list.size()+"");
 }
```

Remove all the code from onActivityCreated() method.

Comment: I got error!!-  java.lang.NullPointerException
            at artha.ordermaking.KOT.CreateOrderFragment.onCreateView(CreateOrderFragment.java:36)

Comment: At which line you got Error? Show me that one.

Comment: ListView menuList=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list); in this line got null pointer exception

Comment: @Rashid just see my answer properly.. here (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list) not view its rootView. so change (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list)

Comment: @Rashid Refer your `Listview` in context of `rootView` not `view`  as `ListView menuList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list);`

Comment: @PiyushGupta +1 from my side ;)

Comment: @Rashid Just see from this **Log.e("list menu--",listMenu.size()+"");** have you got proper size when you r retrieving data from database?

Comment: E/list menu--﹕ 5 ya.. I got all 5 values from db.

Comment: @Rashid Do one thing move this line **menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);** to after this line **menuList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list);**

Comment: @Rashid Update your question with the changes which you have made in your code.

Comment: @GrIsHu Kem hamna thi on9 nathi hoti?

Comment: @Rashid Just check when you are fetching data from database if is it getting same data or problem is in your adaper? after that i will tell you.!

Comment: @PiyushGupta can i ask one thing?? i have read that by giving list view height as ' android:layout_height="0dp" ' will be performance oriented. other than giving "wrap content" ??

Comment: This will be used android:layout_height="0dp" when you have given weight to ListView at that time its height or width must be 0px depends on orientation of Linear layout. And if you set wrap_content means it shows its original height or width.

Comment: Thank you. I am a self learner and i was working on this for two days. Once again thank you.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Cursor getting 5 elements. but cursor in not moving to next.
Cursor points only to first one always

Comment: if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MenuData menuData= new MenuData();
//Function to set Bean class values.

menuList.add(menuData);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
 ListView menuList;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_new_order_list_sections, container, false);

    menuList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearer_menu_order_list);
    DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    listMenu = helper.getMenuItem();
    Log.e("list menu--",listMenu.size()+"");
    MenuListAdapter adapter=new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(),listMenu);
    Log.e("list adapter--",""+adapter.getCount());
    menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
    menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return rootView;
}
```

And remove all the code from `onActivityCreated(....)` and give me feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your adapter you could be missing this

```
    @Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view == o;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    container.removeView((View)object);

}
```