# Error with SQLite cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to get all items from the table in sqlite and need to display it in List View.

**Here is my code for getting Items**

```
public List<MenuData> getMenuItem(){
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor=null;
    List<MenuData> menuList = new ArrayList<MenuData>();
    db=getReadableDatabase();
    String query ="SELECT * from "+TABLE_NAME_MENU;
    try{
    cursor = db.rawQuery (query, null );
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e("Error","Null Pointer Exception");
    }

   if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            MenuData menuData= new MenuData();
            menuData.setKEY_ITEM_NAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_NAME)));
           menuData.setKEY_ITEM_CATEGORY(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY)));
            menuData.setKEY_ITEM_CONTENTS(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_CONTENTS)));
            menuData.setKEY_ITEM_TYPE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_TYPE)));
            menuData.setKEY_PRICE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)));
            menuList.add(menuData);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
   return menuList;

}
```

My problem is I got the result menuList of last row of the table and it has same number of rows in table. So the list view has all the same items.

Comment: i didnt get the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the `MenuData menuData= new MenuData()` inside the `do-while` loop so you're creating new objects instead of updating the same object over and over again.

Also, change

```
if (cursor!=null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

to

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

so your code doesn't crash in case there are no result rows. Checking for `cursor != null` is not really necessary.

Comment: @Rashid why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: @laalto No change. Got all same items which is elements of last row in table

Comment: @pskink i am using BaseAdapter.

Comment: @Rashid so use SimpleCursorAdapter, why to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: @pskink i need to do more operations other than showing in ListView.

Comment: @Rashid like what? what operations?

Comment: May be i am wrong.I need to update the list view with images according to data,and need to add one text view with current row,etc.

Comment: @Rashid all of this you can do with a SCA

Comment: @pskink whats the problem of using BaseAdapter?

Comment: @Rashid it doesnt work, does it? thats the problem, you could avoid by just using  a SCA

Comment: @pskink my problem is not with adapter. Problem with the above code. Adapter is working successfully.

Comment: my question  already asked on adapter [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317195/custom-adapter-not-showing-data/22317509?noredirect=1#22317509)

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

plz correct your code with this structure

```
if(cursor.getCount() != 0 && cursor != null)
{
 do
  {
    your values.. 
  }while(cursor.moveToNext())
}
```

all data is store MenuData then Menudata values are attached to Listview..

Comment: All data are attached to a MenuData object and each MenuData object is added to the ArrayList<> to pass to the List View.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your last part of code to:

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
    while(cursor.moveToNext(){
       // your code
     }
}
```

... and are you sure that problem in this code?
Check your datalist. May be your problem in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont't close the cursor. my suggestion of code:

```
public List<MenuData> getMenuItem(){
    List<MenuData> menuList = new ArrayList<MenuData>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME_MENU, null);
    try { 

        if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MenuData menuData = new MenuData();
                menuData.setKEY_ITEM_NAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_NAME)));
                menuData.setKEY_ITEM_CATEGORY(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY)));
                menuData.setKEY_ITEM_CONTENTS(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_CONTENTS)));
                menuData.setKEY_ITEM_TYPE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_TYPE)));
                menuData.setKEY_PRICE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)));
                menuList.add(menuData);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    } finally {
        // close the cursor
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close(); 
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    return menuList;
}
```

Comment: this too dont work. I got list containing the last row elements in the  table.

Comment: Maybe problem is somewhere else, try add some Log.i where data is read from cursor, mayby something is wrong when you display items of menu

Comment: my list got all same elements as i checked.

Comment: i write sample app, works fine whit this code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoxRKemDO1EZXBqUFQ3cjNwdTQ/edit?usp=sharing